# Getting pid of a process running by execute function in QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

How can I get a pid of a process which was run by QProcess.execute(....,....).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can. Also, as QProcess::execute blocks until the termination of the process, the PID wouldn't be of much use anyway. If you want more control over the external process, create a QProcess object.

Comment: Then how can I run a process inside my program using Qt and get its PID?

Comment: @user562549, easy. Create a QProcess instance, call one of the start() methods, then, after it emits the started() signal, you can access its PID using the pid() method. This is the main way of using QProcess, by the way, execute() is just a convenience function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Is there any function in QProcess class which gets pid as an input and kill  the running process?

Comment: @user562549: No, only QProcess::kill(), which only works for the process that QProcess object represents. So if you started the process via QProcess, just keep that QProcess object around and kill() it. If you don't start it via QProcess, I don't think Qt offers a portable kill() function.

Comment: kill() function that takes a PID that is.